# req.body is empty in Node

Tags: node.js, post, request, content-type

React (Client) sent post data through axios. 
but req.body is empty in Node server side.
Tried to use body-parser. but failed.
[attached client side here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVr6z.png)

[attached server code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O81y2.png)

[This is client Axios part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9QZY.png)

Comment: As I am a beginner, I couldn't post the code. Instead, I attached 2 images which shows code. Please help. I struggled with it for 2 weeks.

Comment: Can you show us your axios request?

Comment: Looks like you are submitting the request with mutipart/form-data and your node is parsing for www-urlencoded. Change your request content-type in axios to www-urlencoded.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try.... FYI, Axios part is added. Would you please take a look again?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the Content-Type on the request.

Per default the body-parser "urlencoded" handles only the following:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
```

You can set the type so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  type: 'multipart/form-data'
}))
```

But then you have to parse the "raw body" by yourself, because the body-parser doesn't support multipart.

Comment: With "raw body" i mean the unparsed http body. 

For x-www-form-urlencoded its simple (key1=value1&key2=value2).

For multipart its more complicated. Example: https://ec.haxx.se/http-multipart.html

Answer (score 0):

The body-parser doesn't support decoding multipart/form-data. There are ample of libraries available for parsing multipart-form/data.

I know the [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) library to be working and using it is as simple as this:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

    console.log(`fields: ${fields} /n files: ${files}`)

});
```